# How to attach a file to a request?

Tags: javascript, node.js, unirest

I'm trying to attach a CSV file and make a request to an API. It needs to be uploaded as a file. I've tried `XHR`, `Unirest`, and `Axios`, and none of them work. What is the problem here?
I've tried putting the full path and it's still not working. Also tried doing `fs.createReadStream`

```
var unirest = require('unirest');
    var req = unirest('POST', 'url')
      .field('username', 'user')
      .field('client_id', 'id')
      .field('user_pass', 'pass')
      .attach('file', './test.csv')
      .end(function (res) { 
        if (res.error) throw new Error(res.error); 
        console.log(res.raw_body);
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try set the header to `multipart/form-data`
And I got these example code from the https://www.npmjs.com/package/unirest

```
unirest
  .post('http://mockbin.com/request')
  .headers({'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'})
  .field('parameter', 'value') // Form field
  .attach('file', '/tmp/file') // Attachment
  .then(function (response) {
    console.log(response.body)
  })
```